# Stop a Laravel scheduled command once started?

Tags: php, laravel-5, scheduled-tasks

I have set up a scheduled command for a laravel 5.1 project.

It works, the command has started, but rather foolishly I didn't think about how I might stop it.

Normally you wouldn't want to stop it, but the command is inserting nearly half a million rows into a database table, and I only really wanted to make sure I could start it without being logged into the server.

I will obviously need to run it at some point but not right now, so is there a way to stop the command mid-flow?

Comment: Remove its entry from the Artisan.php.

Comment: kill the process from terminal

Comment: @MubashirAbbas That's not really an option in my case as the command is already running from the App/Console/Commands/Kernal.php file as a scheduled job.  All thats in the artisan.php file is a reference to the kernal file.  And as the job is already going, i'm not sure that would do anything anyway.

Comment: @GauravDave How do I do that?

Comment: pgrep 'pocess_name' and then you will get process id, then do kill -9 process_id OR run htop command and you will get process id then kill that.

Comment: I don't think that works with Laravel artisan commands.  running `pgrep 'command_name'` does nothing

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me after I found a fault in my scheduled code and it was going to keep running for a really long time. SSH into the server.

```
ps -fe | grep artisan
```

then kill PID (PID being the number of the process). Killing the first two results worked for me.

Note: If you are using withoutOverlapping() the process will not start up again unless you change the ->name() to something unique.