# How to undo or stop php artisan schedule:run

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

This is in my dev environment for Laravel 5.3

I am testing out scheduled emails and ran:

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

This worked fine and is sending the emails as expected.

However I actually want this in the crontab file:

```
 * * * * * php /home/test/website/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Since I added that line in the crontab file I was getting two emails sent out. I removed the line so am now only getting one email.

But now I want to reverse/undo/stop/kill that php artisan schedule:run so that I can control the schedule from the crontab file.

I saw this article: [Stop a Laravel scheduled command once started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920015/stop-a-laravel-scheduled-command-once-started)

but the accepted answer ( ps -fe | grep artisan and kill PID ) for that doesn't work for me as I get the message:

```
kill: (PID) - No such process
```

Every time I run

```
ps -fe | grep artisan
```

it seems to have a different PID - not sure what I am doing wrong in this.

I have also halted my vagrant box but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Any suggestions would be great!

---

UPDATE: Just in case future me happens to have the same issue and stumbles on this SO post again - I have not been able to solve this issue and have decided it is no longer worth putting any more time into solving it - will just live with it for now. By taking that line out of the crontab I am only getting one email so all good for now.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this in your code? withoutOverlapping()
 In order to prevent any overlapping.

> $schedule->command('emails:send')->withoutOverlapping()

Comment: Thanks, that does solve the issue of duplicate emails - just still curious about how to stop all schedules completely. I guess I just don't like the idea of something running that I can't control

Answer (score 3):

You can create an artisan command like

1. custom_schedule:process {type} which will store the type i.e reverse/undo/stop/kill in a schedule file in storage
2. custom_schedule:run which will access the schedule file in storage to get the type and then run the Artisan::command('schedule:run') accordingly

---

Then change the crontab to 
* * * * * php /home/test/website/artisan custom_schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: Thanks Ankith, this sounds excitingly good. I am away from my machine but will try it and post an update as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

> kill: (PID) - No such process
>
> I have also halted my vagrant box but that didn't seem to have any
> effect.

Have you checked inside your host machine? Because this looks like you've been running the both or either of artisan and crontab inside your host machine, instead of inside the vagrant box.

Comment: Thanks, as far as I know I have only been running artisan and crontab inside vagrant. I ran "php artisan schedule:run" and "crontab - e" from the same instance of terminal into vagrant. Will see what I can find out further on that though.